# One field in a Crystal Report with a different Select than the rest of the report

Tags: select, crystal-reports, where-clause

I have a table that has a primary key which is a combo of 2 fields:
**ITEM_NO** and
**LOC_ID**

I have a a report made that shows me all the results of an **ITEM_NO** based on **LOC_ID** that is  chosen. So lets say for all items, show me all the fields I need to see where `LOC_ID = '1'`
This is set up in the select record section, however, there is one particular field **(BIN_1)** per record that I want displayed which should show me the value based on `LOC_ID = '3'`, no matter which **LOC_ID** is set in the select expert parameter.

So, even though all the fields on the report show values Where `LOC_ID = '1'`, the **BIN_1** field should show the value where `LOC_ID = '3'` regardless of the parameter set for the rest of the report

I tried this by creating a new formula field in the report with a where clause, but this doesnt seem to work. Anyone here have any better ideas

Answer (score 0):

You may add the table you are selecting from a second time to your report. Maybe rename it to something like "table_loc3". (Inner-) Join "table_loc3" to your original table on ITEM_NO. Add a record selection criteria for "table_loc3" and filter LOC_ID to be 3.